# How to reduce the number of client connections in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-connection

Recently our testing system is experiencing the error:

```
Error connecting to database: (1040, 'Too many connections')
```

And due to the memory limitation, we cannot increase the current max-connections too much. Adding more memory to the server is a short term solution.

The current DB is MySQL and we're using python to do the database programming. Basically, python code would control the test to run on specific node and store the result into the DB. So, open DB, store data, close DB. Every day we had millions of tests to run and store. But I wonder whether there's a way or methodology or philosophy that I could follow from the perspective of programming.

Also, what is the definition of one client connection? In terms of machines number or cores number in total?

Thanks.

Comment: client connection = file handle. e.g. `handle = mysql_connect(...)` is ONE connection. if you run that 500 times in a loop, then you'll have 500 connections. if you're doing `connect(); save_stuff(); disconnect();`, then you should consider doing just ONE connection: `connect(); save_stuff(); save_more_stuff(); save_again(); etc...; disconnect();`

Comment: I only experimented with Python for a week in college ;) but, in other languages, I generally use a singleton-inspired class to provide a shared connection for the entire program (initialized at program launch, and has methods to reconnect on failure, etc...). Unless a program has multiple threads accessing the database at once, and is careful with use of last_insert_id(), it should only need one connection.

Comment: Can you show us how you are connecting to the database with your python script?

Comment: Thanks all you guys. It's helpful. There's a python script just for launching a test on the specific machine. Each test is a job and we are using pbs (qsub) to submit all the test jobs. Every night we have more than 100000 jobs to submit and execute. Each job is launched by that python script on one machine. This python script will only open and close once. Because the minimum unit is one test, I really cannot think any other ways to save more data during one connecting session.